# Webpack looking for index in datatables extension which has none

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, datatables

What I am trying to do is use datatables. I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'datatables.net-dt' in path/src
```

for all the datatables requires when I try to webpack it. I ran webpack with --display-error-details and found the problem to be that it is looking in the datatable directories for an index file of some sort. e.g.

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      path/node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      path/node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      path/node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/index.json doesn't exist
```

I don't understand why it is looking for the index. I have followed all the documentation I can find on webpack and datatables and according to the datatables download section I should only have to add the packages (which I have done) and add the require's part and it should work.

I have looked at the repos for datatables and its extensions and there is no index in any of them. I've googled this in every which way possible and can't find any answer so I'm hoping someone here might have an idea as I have tried many different things which either didn't work or produced even more errors.

This is my index.js

```
require('./index.html'); 
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();
require( 'datatables.net-buttons-dt' )();
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js' )();
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder-dt' )();
require( 'datatables.net-fixedheader-dt' )();
require( 'datatables.net-rowgroup-dt' )();
```

No code after the requires runs so I haven't included it.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "TestCode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": " ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.116.0",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-dt": "^1.4.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-dt": "^3.1.3",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-dt": "^1.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
}
```

and this is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ['json']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: ['raw-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ['-loader'] 
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your require statements don't need an extra `()` at the end. `require('module');` is fine.

Secondly, you have one statement with a `.js` extension. It shouldn't be there because you're requiring *modules*, not *files*.

Finally, to the solution that fixes your problem: *You're missing a **resolve** field in your webpack.config.js*. When you leave the resolve field out, all of the `require()` statements are looking for modules inside your given context folder, which in your case is the source (src) folder (defaults to root folder when not defined).

To solve this problem, add something like the following to your *webpack.config.js*:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
}
```

Or wherever your node modules may be.

The reason webpack is looking for the index, is because it's default. It couldn't find the module you referenced, so it's looking for an index file instead. The reason you're getting multiple errors on the same import is because it's looking for more than one extension.

The extensions default to `extensions: [".js", ".json"]`. This is why you see the *.js* and *.json* in your error logs. (btw this is also why you can leave extensions out of your `require()` statements)

If you need more help understanding webpack feel free to ask, or check out https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ for the documentation on the resolve options for more stuff you can do with resolving your modules.

Comment: So I added that bit of config and it didn't work, so I had a read of the doco you linked and added: mainFiles : ['package.json'] which seemed to work but now I'm getting a weird issue with the AWS SDK which is Uncaught TypeError : util.crypto.lib.createHash is not a function on the utilities library used by the SDK. If you think it's an unrelated issue I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I am quite sure my fix doesn't achieve anything, if I remove the requires() and the mainFiles for datatables the aws stuff works fine.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I should've checked what you're actually trying to require here.

Thing is, datatables.net-dt is a style-only package (only contains css). Webpack doesn't know what to do with those, because they don't include a main file (or an index.js, for that matter). 

You might be able to solve your problem by just requiring the main library and the style separately: `require('datatables.net');` and `require('datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.datatables.css')` etc.

Comment: Will I need to add a css loader of some sort then? On their download page https://datatables.net/download/index it shows how its meant to be used, I don't understand why I'm going so wrong doing it this way, I'm sure there has to be plenty of other people using it this way?

Comment: Yeah, you need to add a css loader. Use the npm install command to install loaders and use `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}` in your `module { rules [ { ... } ] }` config to use them.

Comment: It's meant to be used like that without using *webpack*. In case you haven't noticed, *webpack* ruins a lot of stuff.

Comment: So is webpack a bad thing? is there something better I am meant to use to bundle my code for distribution?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is browserify, but trust me, it's worse than webpack. Using webpack is not a bad thing, it's just a pain in the behind trying to get it to work sometimes.

Comment: I also posted on the datatables forum, and from the admin there was told to import the datatables stuff directly without the extensions e.g. require( 'datatables.net' ); and that seems to of worked, however none of the css has worked. I have added the style and css loader as well as url-loader for images. Apart of the fix was removing the empty () as well and defining jquery at the beginning var $  = require( 'jquery' ); Anyway it seems to be mostly working now and I can work on the css stuff later. Thanks for the help Rick, Ill mark this as the answer.